# Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am Having some issues with Visual Studio 2012, When build my solution and run the debug it says MSVCP100D.dll is missing

Screen dump:

[image]

When i try to run my program using Release it compiles fine and runs but then it randomly  runs into run time error:

[image]

it then will not build any more underlining these CV_8U & CV_8UC3

I am using OpenCV library, also my code worked perfectly fine on Visual Studio 2010; but i decided to upgrade to 2012.

I would ideally Build my solution using DEBUG..........

Any solutions or suggestions...?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are linking against the opencv libs for Visual Studio 2010. You will have to compile the opencv library for Visual Studio 2012 yourself as the pre-built ones are for Visual Studio 2010.

The information on how to do that can be found under [Installation by Making Your Own Libraries from the Source Files](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation).